# How to retrieve value after subscribe (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have code and I need help for a retrieving data for a variable afte "subscribe".
I use this variable to check the lenght of the list. if list is zero I know it
returned nothing from backend. This problem is that it returns value only the first time
And in the following executions the value comes as "undefined"

```
    // Code in component
    getCode() {
          this.productService.getListCodes(aplicationForm.value)     
          .subscribe(res => { this.listCodes = res );

          console.log("Valor do tamanho lista:" +this.listCodes.length);            
    }
    
    // Service
    getListCodes(map?: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.restService.post(APIConfig.FIND_CODE_API, map);
    }
    
    // Method that uses the variable after "subscribe"
    checkCode() {
        if ( !this.listCodes.length ) {
              return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `getListCodes` is *asynchronous* and so the subscribe happens when it has the data, say after 150 milliseconds. The `console.log` happens straight away hence why it's undefined. Either log *inside* the subscribe or code reactively using RxJS streams

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thanks for reply, I managed to solve it by implementing a loading and called the check method in the sequence. For example:



    getCode() {
 
  
    this.loading.show();
  
          this.productService.getListCodes(aplicationForm.value)     
          .subscribe(res => { this.listCodes = res );
    
    this.loading.hide();
    
    checkCode();
         
    }

Comment: Looks good! I’d personally add `const unsubscribe = /** your subscribe line */` and then call `unsubscribe()` in the `ngOnDestroy()` component lifecycle hook. I always unsubscribe when I subscribe (less mental overhead & safer). That way if the network hangs and user has left component the subscribe doesn’t run unexpectedly after and guaranteed memory clean up.